# use local variable of int data type as parameter in char()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to use a local variable viz. @CV_Max_Len of data type INT as parameter to function CHAR while printing. Following is my code.

```
declare cd_2 cursor for 
    select compact_disc_id, cd_title, price, category 
    from compact_disc_inventory  for read only

declare @CV_Id int
declare @CV_Title varchar(60), @CV_Category varchar(60)
declare @CV_Price numeric(5,2)

open cd_2

declare @CV_Max_Len int
set @CV_Max_Len = (select max(len(cd_title)) from compact_disc_inventory)
print @CV_Max_Len
fetch next from cd_2 into @CV_Id, @CV_Title, @CV_Price, @CV_Category
-- print 'Id      Title                      Price    Category'

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        print convert(varchar(6),@CV_Id) + space(10) +       convert(char(@CV_Max_Len),@CV_Title) + 
            space(5) + convert(varchar(6),@CV_Price) + space(5) + @CV_Category

        fetch next from cd_2 into @CV_Id, @CV_Title, @CV_Price, @CV_Category
    end



close cd_2
deallocate cd_2
```

But I get following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near '@CV_Max_Len'.
```

Any help?

Comment: @ocasoprotal, How to type it in the proper format in the first place only? Can you guide me a little? Thanks

Comment: Just mark your sourceode and press the icon with the two curly braces {} above the input field. You could also always edit your post afterwards with the linke titled _edit_ beneath your post. BTW: I find your sourcecode very hard to read with all the mixed in declare statements.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Forget about implementation. It looks like you want to blank-pad a string. Do you want to left or right pad? How do you want to handle truncation? There are ways to do all of this; a CHAR datatype is not required (nor is what you are trying to do even possible).

Comment: @srutzky, if I use following

Comment: Basically I want to print a variable named @ CV_Title which is of data type VARCHAR(60). But since this data type when printed ignores spaces in the field value, the next variable that gets printed gets mixed up with @ CV_Title. I want proper spacing between the two variable being printed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as asked: use something along the lines of the following:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(60),
        @MaxLen INT,
        @Len INT

SET @Test = 'This is a test.'
SET @Len = LEN(@Test)
SET @MaxLen = 30


SELECT @MaxLen,
       '~' + @Test + '~',
       '~' + @Test + REPLICATE(' ', @MaxLen - @Len) + '~'
```

However, unless there is a technical reason requiring you to use PRINT statements to output a result set to the Messages tab, you would be **MUCH** better off using one of the two following options *without* the CURSOR (both of which can do columnar format):

- SQLCMD command-line utility
- "Results to File" or "Results to Text" query output options

Comment: what is the difference between CHAR(30) & CHAR(@ variable name)? This is what is causing error.

Comment: @Lalu: the difference is that the CHAR(variable) syntax is invalid. It only takes a literal INT. Using the REPLICATE() function as shown in my answer accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
convert(char,@CV_Max_Len)
```

not

```
convert(char(@CV_Max_Len),@CV_Title)
```

Comment: @ehethan, @ CV_Title is the variable that I want to print. It is a column of VARCHAR(60) data type. I want to convert it to CHAR type while printing, with parameter which is maximum length of the column CV_Title to maintain proper indenting.